# Should all code be in classes - and only main class be called once?

Tags: python

Every time when I coded something, it was pretty much just 1 file without any classes (just a bunch of methods) and I would run it through command line.

That, of course, is a very bad practise and cannot really work for any bigger application.

Now that I finally want to build something bigger, I'm a bit confused on where the code should be executed. Let's take an example.

I have a json file with items a person has, and I have another json file with prices for each of those items, along with quantity I already have (higher quantity = lower price being offered etc).

Now I want to make an offer to this person, saying which items and for how much I'd buy them from him.

This is the outlay of my design:

```
class Person(object):
    ...
    def getInventory(self):
        return self.inventory

class Inventory(object):
    ...
    def getInventory(self):
        return self.inventory

class Main(object):
    person1 = Person(someArgs)
    haveInventory = Inventory(someArgs)

    def run(self):
        ... do calculations ...

main = Main()
main.run()
```

Does this make sense?

P.S.: My own inventory and person's inventory have different structure and so inventory cannot really be person's subclass.

Comment: That looks like you're trying to write Java in Python. Please don't do that. BTW, you can't have "1 file without any classes (just a bunch of methods)" because methods are functions that belong to classes, i.e. they're a special kind of attribute. Perhaps you meant "1 file without any classes (just a bunch of functions)".

Comment: There is almost never a case to have a class called "main" because you already have a `__main__` in your file. On top of that it makes very little sense from OOP perspective to have a class called `main` because what sort of object it represents anyway?

Comment: @wobbily_col: It's not _particularly bad_ Python code, but it tends to be more verbose than it needs to be, eg unnecessary use of getters & setters instead of simple attribute accesses. Of course, there are times when a class does need getters and setters, but Python's descriptor syntax makes that transparent to the caller.

Comment: @PM2Ring TIL methods are functions inside classes (thought they are just synonym to a function).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with standalone functions if they are stand-alone.  If they operate on attributes of an object, make a class and make them methods of the class.

It is good practise to have a `main` function, and invoke that if and only your python file is being run directly.  (This means you can import the file into other files, and use the classes.)  Thus something more like:

```
class Person(object):
    ...
    def getInventory(self):
        return self.inventory

class Inventory(object):
    ...
    def getInventory(self):
        return self.inventory

def main():
    person = Person(someArgs)
    haveInventory = Inventory(someArgs)
    ... do calculations ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

... but don't be afraid of functions.  You don't *have* to use classes (which is another way of repeating "PM 2Ring"'s comment: "Please don't try to write Java in Python).

Comment: What would happen if I have a GUI for my app? Do I do the calculations inside some method of the given GUI object or where do I do 'stuff' with the data? My point is - I can create all these classes, initialise them to what I want etc, but where do I do 'stuff' with them?

Comment: You follow the design shown in the examples for your GUI framework.  As a general rule, you do "stuff" with your classes in the methods of your classes.  (For a GUI framework, your GUI classes usually derive from the framework classes.  Your methods get invoked when the user clicks on your button or whatever.)

Comment: Why would you implement a `main()` function if all you do with it is to use it inside of `__main__`? Just inline it's implementation of it and then you will also be very sure that it is never used out of the desired context.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: So that you can import the script into another script (in order to use `Person` and `Inventory`, and other functions), without running the main program of this script.  The line `if __name__ == "__main__":` will execute when the script is imported, but `__name__` *won't* be `"__main__"`, so the main program won't execute. (One particular usage of this, is to have a test program for every library embedded as the `main` function.  Import the library and use it, or run the library and test it.)

Comment: @MartinBonner if you plan to use it outside and want this as a function then you need to at the very least rename it, as `main()` is meaningless name.